# Why is "ton image" correct and not "ta image"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre, possessif, syntaxe

Isn't the pronoun supposed to match the noun genre?
If "image" is feminine shouldn't we use "ta"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Ta* is generally used for feminine nouns  and *ton* for masculine nouns… *but* before a vowel sound, *ta* is never used. In French [hiatuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_%28linguistics%29) are commonly avoided by resorting to [elisions](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lision) or other grammatical artifices.

Thus, “*ton image*”, pronounced `/tɔ̃.n‿i.maʒə/`, just like “*ton idée*”, “*ton ubiquité*”, “*ton histoire*”…

Similarly the possessive articles *ma* and *sa* become *mon* and *son* before vowel sounds.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Stéphane's answer, I would say that it is very similar to the "n" in "an" before a noun in English.

You say "an action" or "an elevator" because it's easier to enunciate than "a action" or "a elevator".

Comment: Euphonically, it's not just very similar, it is the same principle; otherwise, it's the cause of a horrible transgression on fundamental rules, that personnally I'd soon do away with  ;  who knows whether modifications of the possessives in a way similar to the modification of the English article wouldn't be a much happier choice : "mann", "tann", "sann". After all, we do have to say "[mon nimage]" ; is it not much less extravagant to say  "[mann nimage]" from the poinnt of view of grammar ?

Answer (score 0):

“Ton image” is correct and not “ta image” because in French, the possessive adjective has to agree in gender and number with the noun it modifies, not with the person who owns it. However, when the noun is feminine and begins with a vowel or a silent h, the masculine possessive adjective is used to avoid a hiatus. A hiatus is an awkward sound that occurs when two vowels are pronounced one after another. For example:

Ton image (your picture) is correct because “image” is a feminine noun that begins with a vowel. Using “ta image” would create a hiatus between the two a’s.
Ta montre (your watch) is correct because “montre” is a feminine noun that begins with a consonant. Using “ton montre” would not agree with the gender of the noun.
Mon amie (my female friend) is correct because “amie” is a feminine noun that begins with a vowel. Using “ma amie” would create a hiatus between the two a’s.
Ma voiture (my car) is correct because “voiture” is a feminine noun that begins with a consonant. Using “mon voiture” would not agree with the gender of the noun.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already got well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).