# Quelle est la règle pour utiliser « mon » avec des noms féminins ?

Tags: prononciation, genre, déterminants, possessif

Je suis brésilien et j'apprends le français avec l'aide d'un ami.

Il y a quelques jours, quand j'ai dit : « ma expérience », mon ami m'a dit que la forme correcte est « mon expérience », même si « expérience » est un mot féminin.

Alors, quelle est la règle exacte pour ça ?

Est-ce la même chose pour tous les mots qui commencent avec une voyelle ?

Comment: See also http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/why-is-ton-image-correct-and-not-ta-image

Comment: Pensez aussi à mon ami et mon amie.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**La règle** :
Quand le déterminant possessif *ma, ta* et *sa* se trouve devant un mot féminin qui commence par un son voyelle, on emploie *mon, ton* et *son*. Ceci pour éviter d'avoir à prononcer deux voyelles à la suite.

- Ton expérience.
- Mon idée.
- Son enfance.

**Mots commençant par la lettre *h* :**
Quand le h est muet, c'est le son suivant qui est pris en compte :

- Mon heure /œʁ/.
- Mon hypothèse /ipɔtɛz/.

Quand le h est aspiré, le mot commence par le son consonne /h/ et donc on ne fait pas la substitution :

- Ma harpe.

Il ne s'agit que d'une question de proximité phonétique et donc s'il y a un adjectif entre le nom et le déterminant c'est l'adjectif qui est considéré et pas le genre du mot :

- Mon horrible voiture.
- Sa belle idée.

On ne peut pas faire l'élision de la voyelle du déterminant comme on le fait pour les articles *le* et *la* pour éviter la rencontre de deux voyelles.

Pour répondre à la question de @sumelic en commentaire :
À ma connaissance les mots français féminins commençant par la lettre *y* (semi voyelle) commencent tous par le son /j/ qui est un son **consonne**

- Ma yourte /juʁt/.
- Ma yaourtière /jauʁtjɛʁ/.

Pour les mots qui commencent par les lettres *hy* et où le *h* est muet c'est la prononciation de la lettre *y* qui est prise en compte :

- Mon hypothèse /ipɔtɛz/.
- Mon hydre /idʁ/.

Comment: Une question: "y" est compris dans les voyelles, oui or non? Dois-je dire "mon yaourtière" ou "ma yaourtière"? Je suppose que je dois dire "mon hièble"/"mon yèble" parce qu'on dit "l'hièble"/"l'yèble" et pas "la hièble"/" la yèble."

Comment: Nevermind, I found a [paper](http://www.academia.edu/2481999/French_and_Italian_Glides_in_OT_a_Phonology_Morphology_Orthography_interaction) that talks about elision (and presumably liaison applies the same way) before words that start with /j/. Looks like it should be "ma yaourtière" since it is derived from a foreign loanword.

Comment: If you are brazilian, you may have some Spanish skills, to illustrate it, it's almost the same rule for "el hambre/la misma hambre", whereas in Spanish, it's because of the tonic accent.

Comment: @sumelic I was editing my answer to answer your comment. It was worth an addendum.

Comment: Merci pour l'explication!

Comment: Pensez aussi à mon ami et mon amie.

Answer (score 5):

Oui.

> Le féminin **ma** est remplacé par **mon** devant une voyelle ou un h «non aspiré» : *mon amie, mon habitude*.

Source [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mon)

Note that in old French, elision was made instead of using the masculine possessive adjective:

> **m**'amie (my (girl) friend)
>   **t**'amie (your ...) instead of *ton amie*
>   **s**'amie (his/her ...) instead of *son amie*

Comment: Merci pour les corrections. :)

Comment: @elias Não há de quê!

Comment: +1 Oui! Absolument et merci pour le rappel de l'AF dont il subsiste quelques traces de nos jours en raison d'agglutinations curieuses. La sœur de ton père (*t'ante*) étant devenu un limite pléonastique *ta tante*. :-)