# Possessive pronouns before a feminine word starting with a vowel

Tags: possessif

It's been many years since I had French, so I am in doubt about a very basic thing. Let's say you want to say *her school*. *école* is feminine, so you'd expect *sa*, and thus *s'*. However, Google Translate seems to make each feminine word starting with a vowel masculine when using a possessive. It returns *son école*. When trying to translate *that school*, though, it correctly translates to *cette école*.

So is this a bug in Google Translate, or is it indeed the case that *sa + feminine-starting-with-vowel* becomes *son feminine-starting-with-vowel*? It feels unnatural to use *son* for me.

Comment: "When a feminine word starts with a VOWEL or a mute H, you won’t use “ma, ta, sa” BUT “mon, ton, son” (the masculine form) for a reason of pronunciation – to avoid a clash of vowels".    https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/how-to-better-understand-french-possessive-adjectives  and  https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/euphonic-adjectives/

Comment: Same phenomenon in Spanish: ***El** agua esta frí**a***

Comment: See also: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20304/quelle-est-la-r%c3%a8gle-pour-utiliser-mon-avec-des-noms-f%c3%a9minins , https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/why-is-ton-image-correct-and-not-ta-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR It's correct to do so.

You're right to identify *s'* as another way that French could have fixed the vowel + vowel problem ([hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics))), but the apostrophe strategy is reserved for very few words.

Much more common is the liaison strategy, where a consonant turns up. Usually that's done by pronouncing the otherwise silent last consonant of a word, as in "le**s** arbres".

Other times it's done by inserting a consonant out of nowhere, as in "Sera-**t**-il ?"

And in this case, we have the very interesting solution of switching to the masculine possessive, which has that convenient consonant **n** on the end!

Notice that if something else comes between them to fix the hiatus, we see the feminine as expected:

> Voici **mon** école.
>
> Voici **ma** belle école.

If there's something else but it doesn't fix the hiatus, then we still need *mon*.

> Voici **mon** excellente école.

---

P.S. If someone knows the etymology to this, I'd love to see it. As far as I can tell from [the TLFi entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/sa), *sa* is how the feminine possessive always looked. (Whereas if it originally looked more like *son*, then we could have wondered if instead of "switching to" the masculine, an older form was just retained.)

Comment: I really need to freshen up on my French. It seems such a silly mistake. Thanks!