# Une application....Ton application ?

Tags: grammaire

Just wondering why the word 'application' or 'appli' seems to be feminine but from what I've noticed and French speakers have told me it is normally used as masculine in the sense "ton application" but feminine in cases like "une application".

Just wondering if this is correct and perhaps why this is.

Comment: mon/ton/son/ma/ta/sa/mes/tes/ses is "accorded" with the genre of the word. But because of sounds, we use mon/ton/son when the next word starts with a voyel or slient "h". See there: http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-determinants-possessifs-79.php If you speak Spanish, the reason can be analogical to "el hambre" instead of "la hambre", but allow "la misma hambre" (but here it's due to the tonic accent)

Comment: That is not a duplicate because its all in French.

Comment: The second Q&A ([Why is “ton image” correct and not “ta image”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7647/3177)) is entirely in English... Thanks!

Comment: @onvousaouï unfortunately that question is extremely specific just like mine. I doubt anybody would find that one over mine. Also the answers for that question are worse than the answer given here for my question. The question in French was a lot better but unfortunately only available in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it sounds strange to put two vowels next to each other like 'm**a** **a**pplication', so the masculine possessive is used instead, to create the liaison (letter 'n'), which makes the sentence flow easier when spoken. Remember this applies too if the second letter is a vowel and the first is 'h'.

Another example: 'mon identité'.

Comment: Ok I see. So the masculine is used with all feminine words that begin with a vowel...when followed by ton/mon etc?

Comment: @Hasen Yep, thaat is correct :)