# Pourquoi est ce que l'on dit "ton adresse" alors que le mot est féminin ?

Tags: articles, accord, genre, possessif

Malgré le fait que cela sonne mieux ... Logiquement un déterminant féminin ("ta") devrait être utilisé étant donné que le mot est féminin ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is "ton image" correct and not "ta image"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7647/why-is-ton-image-correct-and-not-ta-image)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Effectivement, c'est parce que le nom en question commence par une voyelle que l'on utilise 'Ton' à la place de 'Ta', afin de faciliter la prononciation.

Ainsi on prononcerait cela : Ton n'adresse

Il y a d'autres exemples de ce genre :

> Ton allure
>
> Ton histoire (exception car ici le h est muet)
>
> Ton eau

C'est purement par souci de prononciation.